# Android: Get Time Spent Per Activity

Tags: android, frameworks, android-activity, android-intent, usage-statistics

Firstly, I'm not looking for time spent on a given application. There is already "an app for that", `com.android.settings/.UsageStats`, and a good deal of supporting code in the AOSP `frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/am/UsageStatsService.java`, etc.

The code that I've examined so far does not seem to record elapsed time spent *on particular `<activity>`s*. I have thought to get this information two ways, but feel there must be something cleaner and simpler, that leverages more existing code. The ideas have been:

1. Instrument the base `Activity` class `onPause()` and `onResume()`, to hack in a timestamp, and log the info some place (probably a SQLite database.)
2. Instrument the `Context` class, to make note whenever `startActivity()` and friends are called.

So what do you think -- anything better than those options? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Google analytics for android tries to track the average time spent in an Activity. Have you looked into it?

Comment: Hi Chuck, thanks for bringing this up. That is a step too fine of resolution, though, I think (on a continuum to per-app, within-app, and then within-activity-within-app.)

Answer (score 2):

> So what do you think -- anything better than those options?

Anything is better than #2, which requires custom firmware.

#1 is your only option within the SDK for API Level 13 on down AFAIK.

API Level 14 (a.k.a., Android 4.0) added in `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`, which you can register via `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks()` called on your `Application` (e.g., `getApplicationContext()`). I haven't used these yet, but it would appear that you can arrange for a single listener to be notified of activities coming and going, avoiding forcing you to extend some common base `Activity` class with your desired logging.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, thank you for the reply! Yes, my intention was that both would involve a custom framework.jar. My use case is not applications development -- I'd prefer not to modify any App code if possible (and then there are of course cases when it'd not be possible anyhow.)

WRT #1, I didn't mean to extend Activity within an app, but rather to directly and barbarically edit the Activity.java implementation.

Comment: @Jameson: Ah, OK. Most people asking questions on SO are doing normal SDK development. If you are creating custom firmware, your option #1, or perhaps backporting the `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` and using those, would probably meet your needs. The danger with #2 is that you don't know if there are other code paths that start up activities that don't go through `startActivity()`.