# How much time user spend in certain activity of fragment?

Tags: java, android

I want to get the number of times that user spend in certain activity or fragment in my application and save it to my database. Is there any way?

Someone say use Firebase Google Analytic but I want to do it inside my app.

Comment: You can use the solution mentioned here using  Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778990/android-get-time-spent-per-activity

Comment: create a custom timer, initialize it in your onCreate method and stop it in onStop method. When you stop it calculate the lapse time and make a request to save it your db or server wherever you like in background. We use appdynamics for the same purpose and I guess they do something similar.

Comment: @morteza moradi see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this Simple steps without any timer or service. I do this things for many of my applications. Hope this help you out.

1.) Declare two objects start, end on each activity which you want to add time to database. For E.g.

```
long startTime;
long endTime;
```

2.) Now inside activity onCreate() do something like this.

```
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

3.) Now When you close the activity and move to another activity inside onDestroty() do something like this.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
   endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   long timeSpend = endTime - startTime;
   // Insert timeSpend in databse.
   // you can also convert the timeSpend to hours, minutes, seconds.
   super.onDestroy();
}
```

You can also use the above code inside  onStop() if you don't want to code inside onDestroy().

Comment: for the fragments, which lifecycle pair method - ( onResume, onPause ) or ( onStart, onStop) should be used?